# linux red hat + how to start as single user mode from grub

Tags: linux, grub

I have this in my linux machine

```
  grub>
```

how from this I start the linux machine as single user mode?

in order to update some file after boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RHEL < 7, quoting RHEL [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html):

> At the GRUB splash screen at boot time, press any key to enter the GRUB interactive menu.
>
> - Select Red Hat Enterprise Linux with the version of the kernel that you wish to boot and type a to append the line.
> - Go to the end of the line and type single as a separate word (press the Spacebar and then type single). Press Enter to exit edit
>   mode.

For RHEL >= 7 [Source](https://ma.ttias.be/boot-in-single-user-mode-on-centos-7-rhel-7):

Scroll down until you find the actual kernel line. It starts with `linux16 /vmlinuz-...` and will span a couple of lines. You're now looking for the `ro` keyword in the kernel linux, which would start the OS with a read only (ro) file system, replace `ro` with `rw init=/sysroot/bin/bash`.

Then hit CTRL+X to boot.